# Mapping Model classes to tables, after creation of tables in the database through Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

In an already existing project that uses Hibernates for the Data Access Layer.
I have seen a class having the following relation

```
@Entity
Class Student
{
  @Id
  private int sId;

 @OnetoOne
 @JoinColumn(name=addressId)
 private Address address;

 // getters and setters;
}

@Entity
Class Address
{
 @Id;
 private int aId;

 private String street;
}
```

1. The tables are already created first in the DB, and then the ORM mappings are made, they are not generated with the Model classes.
2. In the database I see that the,table Student has the column aId, repeated.

Can you please let me know, how is it possible, even though we have specified it as One to One relation.

Comment: logically what is the relation between student and address? can a student have multiple addresses? Or Does student has only one address?

Comment: Since There is OneToOne relation with Address, It will have aId for referencing. If you will use ManyToOne relation in Address for Student, Then you can query that address belong to which student.

Comment: Logically a student can have only one address 
and multiple students can have the same aId @PrasadKharkar

Comment: http://www.thejavageek.com/2014/01/15/jpa-many-one-association/

Comment: Here my only question is even though the jpa specified that it is one to one relation, how is it possible that the aid is duplicated in the Student table